# R Shiny Bookmark Button Flaw

Tags: r, shiny

I have found a major flaw with the `bookmarkButton()` in Shiny. If you have any text inputs and do not enter anything in them, when you go to bookmark your app's state and restore it, it gives you an error:

`Error in RestoreContext initialization: Failed to parse URL parameter "txt"`

This is because the URL that the `bookmarkButton()` creates always has the value of text inputs between `%22`s. When there's no input, the URL looks like this `...TextInputID=%22%22`. If you enter something in the text input the URL will look something like `...TextInputID=%22foo%22`.

See this example app to reproduce this error. Is there a way around this? Maybe a way to get in there and edit the URL that the `bookmarkButton()` produces?

```
ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    textInput("txt", "Enter text"),
    checkboxInput("caps", "Capitalize"),
    verbatimTextOutput("out"),br(),
    sliderInput("slider", 'Choose a number:', 1, 100, 20),
    verbatimTextOutput("sliderOut"),
    bookmarkButton()
  )
}
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$out <- renderText({
    if (input$caps)
      toupper(input$txt)
    else
      input$txt
  })

  output$sliderOut <- renderText({
    input$slider
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

Comment: Your example runs fine for me (on Mac with latest Shiny from CRAN) on Chrome, Safari and Firefox. So it may be a browser issue if you're using another browser.., or maybe it's an old version of Shiny?

Comment: Interesting. I tried it again, and it now seems to be fine. It is putting the text input value between quotes instead of `%22`. It may have been a browser issue, but it seems to be working now with Chrome. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be working on mac systems but not Windows systems. I tried it on a mac and it worked, but the very same example (above) does not run on Windows. I used Chrome on both systems.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a platform issue. I reproed your problem on Windows. I opened an issue for it in our issue tracker: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1689. You can keep track of it and see when there's a fix. Hopefully it will be soon! Thanks for the report

Comment: It looks like this happens when Windows is the hosting platform. The good news is that this would only happen in development, because the Shiny apps in production must be served off of Linux machines. The bad news, of course, is that it the behavior on the development platform is wrong. It looks like it should be a straightforward fix, though.

Comment: It turns out that it's due to a bug in R itself on Windows. See https://github.com/jeroen/jsonlite/issues/180 and https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17265. Hopefully there will be a workaround in jsonlite relatively soon and updating it should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks to all. I hope this is fixed soon! The temporary and unideal workaround is to force the user to enter something, say a space, in each text input. Then bookmarking will work, but the next user will need to go through and delete the space in each text input, but at least the values of all other inputs will be bookmarked.